# Thread working unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a simple java program and I was hoping for an output like

```
go
hello 
bye //pause for 2 seconds
hello
```

**But it is giving an output like**

```
go
bye
hello //pause for 2 sec
hello
```

**Programme:**

```
class Tread{
      public static void main(String[] args){
           Hello h= new Hello();
           Thread t= new Thread(h);
           System.out.println("go");
           t.start();
           System.out.println("Bye");
      }
}

class Hello implements Runnable{
     public  void run(){
           System.out.println("hello");
           try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
           }
           catch(Exception e){ }
           System.out.println("hello");
    }
 }
```

Please, can anybody tell me why i am not getting the desired otput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is unpredictable since 2 threads try to write something on the output simultaneously. The JVM specs do not specify the order of the operations:

- you have the main thread that starts another thread
- after that, the main thread and the other thread both print something.

So, all of this is implementation dependant: somebody may use another JVM, one day, and/or another operating system, and he could then have another behaviour. With your JVM, on your environment, you may encounter millions of run of this program writing output in the same order. But it does not mean that it will never change in the future.

If you want the sequence of operations to be done according to a particular order, you need to use some locks, or `synchronized` keyword to access resources.

Thinking it will always behave the same often leads to mistakes, that happen only occasionally, and that we call **race conditions**.

Comment: but i ran the programme for 20-30 time but output is coming same

Comment: even once it should print hello befor bye

Comment: Yes, this is implementation dependant: somebody may use another JVM, and/or another operating system, and he would then have another behaviour. With your JVM, on your environment, you may encounter millions of run of this program writing output in the same order. But it does not mean that in another environment, it will be the same.

Comment: so how should I use synchronized here to show hello before the bye?

Comment: If what you want is to print *bye* only when the 2nd thread is terminated, simply add `t.join()` just before printing *bye*. This is a way to wait for thread termination.

Comment: what do you mean by *an output like this*?

Comment: I mean Bye printing before hello

Comment: Yes this is normal: everything unspecified may happen, especially when we talk about concurrent programming. Search *race condition* on Google, you will see the amazing number of times such things happen!

Answer (score 0):

I guess because it is on another thread, independent from main program.
Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Hello h= new Hello();
        Thread t= new Thread(h);
        System.out.println("go");
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}

class Hello implements Runnable{
    public  void run(){
        System.out.println("hello");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```